# Should a topic tag be avoided because it might be a spoiler?

Tags: discussion, tags, spoilers

Bringing up because of this question:

[What does Yoda's species eat?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223179/what-does-yodas-species-eat)

I think it would be appropriate to tag the question correctly with the extra tag (see comments to question), obviously OP does not because it *could* spoil (not sure how).

Thoughts?

Comment: Normally, no. If it’s about a specific work it needs the specific tag. However, this question is applicable to the canon as a whole so doesn’t really need the specific work tag.

Comment: Also, mini-Yoda's face has been splashed over every newspaper and online journal for weeks now. The mere presence of this character is the worst kept secret in Star Wars history

Comment: I can see that argument @TheLethalCarrot - at least better than the one being attempted in the question re: spoilers. To me it's worth adding because the question clearly came about because of the new series, so it's worth adding imo

Answer (score 15):

It's not an inherent spoiler because you're not obviously given the context. The tag would be only a minor spoiler, and only if you view the question. In this case, the question is about a broader topic to try and avoid a spoiler, so it doesn't need the series tag. If the question's title were (massive [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) spoiler ahead)

> In *The Mandalorian*, why did Yoda's clone eat a frog?

then I would be inclined to edit, but it would need the series tag, since it would be specific to that series.

## We shouldn't avoid tags just because they are potential spoilers

Tags exist so we can easily reference questions later. Not tagging a question about a specific topic is a disservice to people looking for the question.

Answer (score 10):

## Tag questions properly!

**The system is set up for the user who does not want to be spoiled to take steps to do so.**

Luckily, SE provides us with an easy avenue to do so, *ignoring tags*.

If a user wants to avoid spoiler for a specific franchise they can if the question is tagged properly.

For the particular question I have no reason to hide general [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) questions, however I definitely do want to hide [the-mandalorian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-mandalorian) questions as I have not started watching it yet. **If the question is not tagged properly I can not do this.**

Comment: Don't you have to have the question on your screen before you can see the tag?